# Nextjs _app layout is not persistent, it loads new on page change

Tags: javascript, web, next.js, frontend

i've created a `_app.js`:

```
const MyApp = ({Component, pageProps})  =\> {

    const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>)
    
    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)

}
export default MyApp
```

two pages `about.js` and `works.js` which just return an empty div:

```
export default function Works(){
    return(
        <div></div>
    )
}
```

and my default layout is defined as the following:

```
const Layout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Layout;
```

but whyever it also loads the Navbar when i try to navigate from /works to /about with (lies in my navbar):

```
...
<div className={styles.item}><a href={'/about'}>about</a></div>
...
```

I'm using next 13.2.3 and idk why it doesn't work :(

I already tried to remove the per-page layout and go with a shared layout for all the pages, but it had the same outcome - so i went back to my per-page, which i need because i want the default page without Navbar and all the other pages should have one.

Other solutions on StackOverflow didnt help, so i'm trying to figure out whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I was using <a> Components for my transition between pages, but i'm supposed to use <Link> from next/link :D

```
<div className={styles.item}><Link href={'/about'}>about</Link></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy below code to your _app.js file

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";
import MyLayout from "@/components/layouts/layout";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Layout from "@/components/layouts/layout";


const MyApp = (props)  => {  
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;
  
    return (
      <Layout>
       <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    );

}
export default MyApp
```

Copy below code to your layout.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import Head from "next/head";
import  {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const Layout = ({children}) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <div>
            {router.asPath === '/' ? null : <Navbar/>}
            <main>{children}</main>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

This will render layout on all pages except /about page

PS: I had to seprately do `❯ npm i react-moment@1.1.3`   to run you project

Comment: Still the same outcome, it still reloads my Navbar

Maybe more code insight would be helpful, here is the project:
https://github.com/yuuuudini/webdini2.0/tree/master/webdini

Comment: So you do not want your Navbar component on /about page. Am i right ?

Comment: I have edited my answer above, Let me know if it works as expected

Comment: I want it on every page except my start page, so not on / but on /works, /about, /[insert other url names here]

I will try it later, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: well then replace "/works" with just "/"

Comment: Its still the same outcome.. the Navbar is refreshed on when i change the page:

https://streamable.com/hs7qnz